# How do I add FooterTemplate to GridView with BoundFields

Tags: asp.net, gridview, footer

Hope you have a good weekend.
At long last I have got some editing/delete eventer to work with LINQ support.
I have an Add record event which I know is working, but after trying a part, I do not know how I am adding some textbox's in my footer.

So it is a row from header and down to footer, without the move to the right or the left.
Can some help me !?

[image]

My code is

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gdview"  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="test_id" OnRowCancelingEdit="gdview_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDeleting="gdview_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="gdview_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="gdview_RowUpdating"
        BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal" ShowFooter="true">
        <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Test CAT" DataField="test_cat">
            <ItemStyle Height="20px" Width="150px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Test INFO" DataField="test_info">
            <ItemStyle Height="20px" Width="150px" />
        </asp:BoundField>  
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Test NUMBER" DataField="test_number">
            <ItemStyle Height="20px" Width="150px" />
        </asp:BoundField>   
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Test DATE" DataField="test_datetime">
            <ItemStyle Height="20px" Width="150px" />
        </asp:BoundField>       
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True">
            <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
        </asp:CommandField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkdel" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete"   OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to delete?')"></asp:LinkButton>      
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4B4B4B" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#242121" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Ok but how with this then work, if i use templates, how do it know what cell to get values from !??

```
 Protected Sub gdview_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
    Using db As New ThedatabaseconnectionDataContext()
        Try
            'getting table
            Dim tbltest As Table(Of testtable) = db.GetTable(Of testtable)()
            'getting an exiting row
            Dim objtest As testtable = tbltest.SingleOrDefault(Function(p) p.test_id = Integer.Parse(gdview.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Value.ToString()))
            If objtest IsNot Nothing Then
                'modifying the row
                objtest.test_cat = DirectCast(gdview.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Controls(0), TextBox).Text
                objtest.test_info = DirectCast(gdview.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Controls(0), TextBox).Text
                objtest.test_number = DirectCast(gdview.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Controls(0), TextBox).Text
                objtest.test_datetime = DirectCast(gdview.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Controls(0), TextBox).Text
                'saving rows added
                db.SubmitChanges()
                gdview.EditIndex = -1
                bindgrid()
                ' Me.lblMsg.Text = "Updated Successfully"
            Else
                'Me.lblMsg.Text = "Employee not found"
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Me.lblMsg.Text = ex.Message
        End Try
    End Using
```

Comment: +1 for asking the question earlier, so I benefit today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with

```
<columns>
  <asp:templatefield headertext="Test" >
    <itemtemplate>
       .... 
    </itemtemplate>
    <footertemplate>
      <asp:TextBox id="TestTbx"   runat="server"/>
    </footertemplate>
  </asp:templatefield>
</columns>
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.footertemplate.aspx

Comment: @Thomas  Replace your boundfield with templatefield and add footer, boundfield is basic field , you cannot customize, i you wish customize you must develop another boundfield and override basic behavior

Comment: Hi Aghilas, plz see my add..Code Behind.

Comment: You modify your code with e.Item.FindControl("IdOfControlInRow")

Comment: Ok so i dont need to add edittemplates to get the edit working then !?

Comment: You need `EditTemplate` if you are planning to edit this field (which now is a `BoundField`). *Usually* columns which were defined as `BoundField` don't seem to be editted on run time. I assume the same case for you. You just want to insert but no edit. So as @AghilasYakoub demonstrated, it's just a `templatefield` to support the functionalists of `insert` using `FooterTemplate`